# Dynamic JSON to model where data with common prefix should go to dictionary

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have JSON like that:

```
{
    "id": "913678a9-63d6-4261-9a4c-d710755c8141",
    "A": null,
    "B": null,
    "C": null,

    "extension_A": "COKOLWIEK",
    "extension_B": "36402User"
}
```

id, A, B, and C are always in model.

and class:

```
string a {get;set;}
string b {get;set;}
string c {get;set;}

@JsonIgnore
IDictionary<string,string> extensions {get;set;} = new Dictionary<string,string>();
```

I'd like to convert Json to object of this class, where all extension_{x} goes into dictionary as KeyValue pair, where key is name of property.

I think about using
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject
and iterate over all properties and add it to dictionary if property name is extension_ ,

but maybe there is better way to do this.

Comment: how about `JsonExtensionData`, for more details :  https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeExtensionData.htm

Comment: @Sajid Thanks, thats what i was looking for. :)